# Different basemaps in OL-Cesium side-by-side example

Tags: openlayers, cesium, ol-cesium

I have an application that has two maps that are linked: a normal map on the left and a globe on the right. The application is based on the example [olcesium side-by-side example](http://openlayers.org/ol-cesium/examples/sidebyside.html).

I would like to use OSM on the map but satellite imagery on the globe. How do I assign a different basemap to the globe?

The way I understand this, both are directly linked, which means if I change something in one of them, the other one will be changed as well. But in my case I would like to use different basemaps.

The globe was created just like in the example, *map* being my original OpenLayers map, and *map3d* the div that holds the globe:

```
var ol3d = new olcs.OLCesium({map: map, target: 'map3d'});
```